# I can't draw a circle in swing

Tags: java, swing, drawing, geometry

I want to draw a circle with red border. 
But nothing draws in my code :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class DrawCircle extends JPanel{

    public DrawCircle() {
        setBackground(Color.green);
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 255,0));
        g.drawOval(100, 100, 50, 50);
        super.paint(g);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new DrawCircle(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call of `super.paint(g)` clears over the circle you draw, change the order:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(new Color(0, 255,0));
    g.drawOval(100, 100, 50, 50);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine and shows in the screen after I change g.setColor(new Color(0, 255,0)); to g.setColor(new Color(255, 0,0)) :D;!

Comment: Well, all that would do is change the color from green to red.

Comment: Oh yeah, you set the background to green, sorry I missed that.

Comment: The **`paintComponent(Graphics)`** method is the correct one to override for painting any `JComponent`..

Comment: It depends if the paint component is lightweight or heavyweight. I'd use `paint` with `JPanel`.

Answer (score 3):

instead of this:

```
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 255,0));
        g.drawOval(100, 100, 50, 50);
        super.paint(g);
    }
```

do this:

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { // you should be overriding paint component, not paint
        super.paintComponent(g); // your super.paint call was painting the background, clearing out the drawing you were doing
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 255,0));
        g.drawOval(100, 100, 50, 50);
    }
```

Comment: it also works paintCompanent() method. I found mistake: must call super.paintCompanent() instead of super.paint()